# Get user addresses in update method Liferay

Tags: liferay, listener

I wanna know when an address was changed, then I implemented a class to override the update method of Address. 
The class works fine, but when I try to get all the addresses of the logged user I can't access, I only get the admin address.

This is my code to get the addresses:

```
List<Address> userAddresses = AddressLocalServiceUtil.getAddresses(user.getCompanyId(), Contact.class.getName(), user.getContactId());
for(Address userAddress : userAddresses) {
    System.out.println(userAddress);
}
```

If I execute this code in other part it works fine, and I get the user address, it doesn't work in the class that override the update.

This is my class:

```
public class MyAddressLocalServiceImpl extends AddressLocalServiceWrapper {
    public Address updateAddress(long addressId, String street1, String street2, String street3, String city, String zip, long regionId, long countryId, int typeId, boolean mailing, boolean primary) {
        System.out.println("Actualizar una dirección");
        try {
        Address oldAddress = AddressLocalServiceUtil.getAddress(addressId);         
        Address aux = getWrappedService().updateAddress(addressId, street1, street2, street3, city, zip, regionId, countryId, typeId, mailing, primary);

        System.out.println("Old Address " + oldAddress);
        System.out.println("New Address " + aux);
    long id_user = AddressLocalServiceUtil.getAddress(addressId).getUserId();
            User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(id_user);      
        System.out.println("Obtenim les addresses");
            List<Address> userAddresses = AddressLocalServiceUtil.getAddresses(user.getCompanyId(), Contact.class.getName(), user.getContactId());
            for(Address userAddress : userAddresses) {
                System.out.println(userAddress);
            }
    } catch (PortalException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

address_ table stores userId and userName of user who add that address thats why you are getting deviation.

From address_ table you can use classpk field as contactId instead of getting contactId from user.